# Calculate the top 5 optimal parcel locker cabinet configurations

Tags: python, optimization, algorithms

Dear Data Science community,

I have the following problem to solve and I'd like to learn which algorithm or approach I can use to tackle it. I don't expect a full solution here but I really want to understand what type of optimization problem I am looking at and expecting to get some pointers.
FYI, I'm using Python, in case you'd like to suggest a certain library.

Problem domain is parcel lockers.

### TLDR;

Calculate the top 5 optimal parcel locker cabinet configurations to accommodate most of the parcel deliveries throughout the year.

### LONG VERSION

- Assume that I start with the data for daily ecommerce parcel
  deliveries to parcel lockers for last year. I know how many parcels
  of which size are delivered to parcel lockers stations for day n (n
  is 1 to 365) in a certain region. Let's say I don't know the exact
  parcel locker station locations but I know each customer's rough home
  coordinates. So data looks like => **array of (day of year, parcel
  size, customer location)**

  - All data is per single parcel, no
    complicated scenarios.
- Now, I want to create my own optimal parcel
  locker network to accommodate those deliveries. Let's say I calculated optimal locations for the parcel locker stations. Now my data looks like this: **array of (day of year, parcel
  size, parcel locker station location)** => customer location is now
  translated to closest parcel locker station location.
- Imagine I'm limited to 3 sizes of lockers and smaller ones can fit in the larger ones.

  - size 1 fits in size 2 and size 3
  - size 2 fits in size 3
- Given those 3 locker sizes I now know which of my parcels fits to which locker size => now my data is: **array of (day of year, min locker size, parcel locker station location)** - now aggregating this data per location tells me how many of which locker size (at minimum) I need at each certain parcel locker station.
- Parcel locker stations are made of locker cabinets which accommodate a certain locker configuration. A fictional locker cabinet configuration would look like: [2 * (size 1), 3 * (size 2), 0 (size 3)] or [1 * (size 1), 2 * (size 2), 1 * (size 3)] etc, etc.

#### The problem I want to solve starts here

- Given that:

  - I can place any number of locker cabinets in a parcel locker station;
  - Each locker cabinet can be maximum 2 meters in height and;
  - Each locker cabinet is a single column of lockers (given that all 3 locker sizes have the same width);
  - For cost purposes I'm limited to producing 5 types of locker cabinet configurations.
- How can I calculate the top best 5 locker cabinet configurations from this data? - Best means:

  - Throughout the year I'll use the minimum amount of locker cabinets;
  - I will also minimize the amount of unhappy customers on peak periods (Christmas, black Friday etc...)
- To simplify, I'm not allowed to add additional lockers on peak days.

Answer (score 0):

That problem could be framed as a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), where items of different sizes must be packed into a finite number of bins.

There are many Python libraries to solve bin packing. Two common packages are [binpacking](https://pypi.org/project/binpacking/) (more specific) and [pywraplp](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/linear_solver/pywraplp.html) (more general).

Comment: thanks for your response - I think bin packing applies when you already know the sizes of the bins and/or containers (or in this case cabinets). I'm actually trying to figure out the best cabinet configurations - so, it is a different approach. Do you mean I should try all possible cabinet configurations and run bin packing and see which ones are best? I want to run it over 10M parcels, I can try but I assume it would be computationally extremely expensive.